# Quarkus compatibility with openjpa and other lib/frameworks?

Tags: java, apache-karaf, openjpa, quarkus

I would really like to use graalVM for its AOT capabilities to reduce dramatically boot time of my Apps. 
When I read that Quarkus.io and graalVM AOT were working well with hibernate I really had the feeling that a big step was achieved. But my app relies on openJPA and migration is not really do-able quickly.
Does someone know if Quarkus /GraalVM has been tested with openjpa?

Another question I have in mind is if Quarkus is compatible of Karaf/OSGI platforms? Any tries around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus has only been tested with Hibernate as a JPA provider. And to be honest Hibernate seems to have been one of the most challenging aspects to integrate into Quarkus. Furthermore, getting Hibernate work with Ahead Of Time metadata required some changes on the Hibernate side itself.

Let's not forget that Quarkus integrations are meant to only be very performant, but to work Out Of The Box in GraaVM native mode as well

Comment: And do you know for  Apache/karaf/OSGI platforms ?

Comment: I do not, but I haven't seen OSGI mentioned at all. I would be very surprised if it worked however...

Comment: The main reason why OSGi is not a target is that dynamic classloading can not be supported by the GraalVM native mode (see https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/LIMITATIONS.md#dynamic-class-loading--unloading).